# Displaying two hrefs into separate columns in a table

Tags: php, html, css, href

I have a problem which I am having difficulty with. I have a system which displays video tutorials. My code below displays the name of the video (eNISATQuestion) and the link to the video (eNISATVideo) as one href.

I want to add another column to display to link to a rating page with a similar layout as the section below.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

With values (eNISATRateRef) and (eNISATRating).

Thanks in advance

```php
<?php

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header("Location: index.php");

$res     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array( $res );

$userID  = $_SESSION['user'];

$query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo, eNISATRateRef, eNISATRating FROM enisatquestion INNER JOIN enisatanswer WHERE
    enisatanswer.eNISATID = enisatquestion.eNISATID AND user_id =
    $userID AND eNISAT_watch = 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

/* A default message if the query fails or there are no records */
$enisatquestion='<h2>Sorry, there are no records</h2>';

if($result) {/* if there is a recordset, proceed and generate html table */
    $enisatquestion = "<table >";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        **$enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";**
    }
    $enisatquestion .= "</table>";    
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">
            <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="content">
                Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="home.php?home">Return to Homepage</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
    href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <h2>Click on the each link to open your tutorial in Windows Media Player<h2>
            <br>
            <?php
                /* output the html table here, below your header */
                echo $enisatquestion;
                /* If the query failed then the default gets displayed */
            ?>  
        </div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: please add your thank yous, if any at the bottom of the post, not before the code examples, and probably move your comments so that the first discuss the code example, then the final question afterwords.  This post has already been flagged.

Comment: I will bear that in mind @BrianThomas in future thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `td` element and add the new data you fetch from the database.

```
**$enisatquestion .= "
  <tr>
    <td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td>
    <td><a href='{$row['eNISATRateRef']}'>{$row['eNISATRating']}</a></td>
  </tr>";**
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris that worked, both columns are inserting into one column so to speak. There is no line down the middle to separate each column which makes it a bit untidy looking, any suggestions for this? Or is this due to my CSS file? Thanks

Comment: you can add to your css: `td:nth-of-type(1) {border-right: 1px solid black;}`

Answer (score 1):

If this line of code...

```
<a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a>
```

...is an exact copy/paste from the code you are using, please mind the double quotes.

```
<a href="{$row['eNISATVideo']}">{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a>
```